# Query a many to many relationship with Entity Framework and .NET 3.5

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, many-to-many

My problem is actually two-fold. First, I'm pretty new to EF but I've used it with some success by taking shortcuts earlier. Though, for this particular project I plan to take the time to learn.

What I have at this point is a very simplistic database structure:

```
Post
===================
Id     Title
-------------------
 1     Hello world
 2     Foo bar baz

Tag
===================
Id     Title
-------------------
 6     test
 7     todo

PostTags
===================
PostId     TagId
-------------------
     1         6
     1         7
     2         7
```

Using EF, it generates a model with two entities: **Post** and **Tag**.

### What I'm trying to accomplish:

I'm attempting to query the model for all posts given an array of tagIds (6 and 7 for instance). However I can't figure out what I need to do to make that work. 
Previously I've cheated in the way that I added an auto-incremental PK to the mapping table (BlogPosts) and added it into the EF-model but it was more of an ugly hack in order to move forward. I'd rather learn how to do it right this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work in EFv4. Try it in EFv1:

```
var tagIds = new int[] { 6, 7 };
var query = context.Tags
                   .Where(t => tagIds.Contains(t.Id))
                   .SelectMany(t => t.Posts);
```

Edit:

I checked it and collection valued parameters + `Contains` were added in EFv4 so above example doesn't work in EFv1. [This thread in MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/095745fe-dcf0-4142-b684-b7e4a1ab59f0/) provides workaround to allow IN operator in EFv1. Another recommended workaround is simply upgrade to EFv4 because there are many other improvements including significant improvement of performance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it does not seem to work with EF 1 which I use. The following exception is thrown: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.